# insertar en arreglo los valores checkbox que esten seleccionados?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, array

mi CH esta conectado con un campo de la  base de datos, como inserto en un arreglo los valores que estén seleccionados?

Comment: Hola user67498. Te invito a repasar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para entender mejor lo que se requiere de tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero se requiere generar una variable de tipo arreglo, posterior generar un bucle y dentro del bucle utilizando selectores css y jquery podras iterar segun sea los checkbox selected que existan... seria algo como lo siguiente:

## HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="A" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="B" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="C" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="D" />
```

## jQuery:

```
var arr = [];

$("input:checkbox[name=check]:checked").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(arr); // print de los items add dentro de tu array...
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Gracias Me sirvió!